# How do I display SVG in .cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to display .svg image on my .cshtml page.

Status404.cshtml

```
@inject Context Session
@{
    Layout = "";    

}

<img src="/workspace/src/Application/wwwroot/img/404.svg" alt="404page"/>

@if(Session.CurrentUser.Language=="ka"){
    <p><ქართული ტექსტი</p>
}

@if(Session.CurrentUser.Language=="en"){
    <p><ENG TEXT HERE</p>
}
```

RESULT:

[image: result]

I tried creating a partial view(renamed .svg to .cshtml) like 404Partial.cshtml and then including it in .cshtml like this :

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("/workspace/src/Application/Views/404Partial.cshtml");
```

But it couldn't find the view.

Comment: Make sure the file path is correct, because the error is saying not Found

Comment: @Bosco I checked. Copied the path using "Copy file path" option. Still same. This is an error : InvalidOperationException: The partial view '/workspace/src/Application/Views/Home/404.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/workspace/src/Application/Views/Home/404.cshtml

Comment: Can you try with `~/workspace/src/Application/wwwroot/img/404.svg`

Comment: @Bosco I did. Result stays the same.

Comment: Can you show your app folder structure pointing to the svg file

Comment: Screenshot for folder structure : http://www.picz.ge/img/s1/1907/15/a/abb5837078d0.jpg

Comment: What you need is `~/img/404.svg` let me know if this works so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @Bosco Yes! <object type="image/svg+xml" data="~/img/404.svg">
</object> worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at your folder structure, this is the tag and path you need to use

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="~/img/404.svg"> </object>
```

Comment: It worked for me but how can I change the color of the svg like this?

Comment: @AsIndeed try `object svg { fill: red; /* Change the fill color to red */ }`

Answer (score 3):

You can try use the Object tag instead.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="path/image.svg">
</object>
```

Comment: Tried it. Only blank page is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for that:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/workspace/src/Application/wwwroot/img/404.svg")))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in the .svg file I did not have  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute

I was able to use `<img src="path/myfile.svg" />` after adding that xmlns in my .svg file:

**myfile.svg:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" />
</svg>
```